# Is there a way to print the live output of a cell in Jupyter Notebook to a MacBook Touch Bar?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, xgboost, macbookpro-touch-bar

Or even to a file or cmd prompt so I can make a script to display it myself?

I am using XGboost on a project of mine and I would like to see the validation results in the touch bar so I don't have to switch between tabs to check up on it.

The terminal results from XGBoost doesn't show the eval metrics so I can't get it from the terminal directly.